# Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview not full width

Tags: jquery, grid

Quick and simple. I'd like to use this tutorial http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

But playing around with the code, I can't figure out how to make the expanded view the size of the grid versus full width.

`.og-expander` being `position:absolute;` doesn't allow me to alter much and still keep it centered.

Any help or guidance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a width to `<div class="container">`. That worked for me when I only wanted 3 thumbs across - it forced the other ones onto a new line and limited the width of the expanded preview. Hope that helps!